# MVC Custom non model object validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a peculiar scenario in which i need to validate an object that isn't my model and get all the ValidationResult objects from it.

So my controller has something like this in it ...

```
public virtual ActionResult(MyObject postData)
{
    ICollection someCollection = DoSomething(postData);

    foreach(Thing t in someCollection)
    {
         // validate t and get any ValidationResult objects
         // put the validation results in the object property.
         // this call isn't real by the way
         t.ValidationResults = t.Validate();
    }
    ...
}
```

Its not my model i'm validating but based on the postdata i'm given i need to validate the collection and where the validation fails I plan to render the failed objects in the collection.

any ideas how I can the ValidationResult objects I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article on [manual validation with data annotations](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) might give you what you need.

Comment: perfect ... it was my implementation that was wrong cheers for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the `ValidationResults` in the `ViewBag` and then render them from there:

```
var list = new List<ValidationResult>();
foreach (Thing t in someCollection)
{
    t.ValidationResults = t.Validate();
    list.AddRange(t.ValidationResults);
}
ViewBag.ValidationResults = list;
```

now, a lot of that code makes a lot of assumptions because you aren't providing a lot of information. But either which way, get those results into an overall list and set them in the `ViewBag`. You can then leverage the `ViewBag` in the view:

```
@foreach (ValidationResult r in ViewBag.ValidationResults)
{
   <!-- render some HTML here  with the r variable -->
}
```

Comment: i don't think i worded the question right ... that validate method doesn't exist (yet) however the object in question has data annotations on it's properties that I want to get the validation results from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate.aspx  ... my problem is how do I implement that.

Comment: +1 for effort ... the solution was sound it was the validation method code i had to figure out.